# Evaluating a double integral with monte carlo integration?

Tags: integration, monte-carlo

I am trying to find an equation that estimates the following integral:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 e^{(x+y)^2} \,dx\,dy$$

where I am given a list of different uniform RV's $m_1,m_2,\ldots$ and $n_1,n_2,\ldots$.

I'm not quite sure how to go about evaluating this double integral?

I know the integral for a single integral over that interval is a summation over n, but how does it work for two integrals where the function is already given?

Any insight would be great!

thank you

Comment: How do you mean "where the function is already given"? How would you do it if the function weren't given?

Comment: $$\begin{align}
u & = x+y \\
v & = x-y \\ {} \\
dx\,dy & = \left| \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \right| \, du \, dv = \frac{du\,dv} 2
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \int_0^1 e^{(x+y)^2} \, dx\,dy \\ {} \\
= {} &  \frac 1 2 \int_0^1 \left( \int_{-u}^u e^{u^2} \,dv \right)\,du + \frac 1 2 \int_1^2 \left( \int_{u-2}^{2-u} e^{u^2} \,dv \right) \, du \\ {} \\
= {} & \frac 1 2 \int_0^1 2u e^{u^2} \, du + \frac 1 2 \int_1^2 (4-2u) e^{u^2} \, du
\end{align}$$
So part of this may fail to be elementary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The measure $dx\,dy$ is is the uniform distribution on $[0,1]\times[0,1].$ So (assuming the uniform random variables are independent—and you should have said something about their joint distribution) the sample mean
$$
\frac 1 k \sum_{i=1}^k e^{(m_i+n_i)^2}
$$
should approximate the value of the integral.

Answer (score -1):

i want to give you the answer only, which I found from a website. I am giving you the link. Hope it will help you. Actually, I don't know how to solve this problem.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB%280%2C1%29%E2%88%AB%280%2C1%29+e%5E%28%28x%2By%29%5E2%29+dxdy